# Content not showing in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web

I have a test website that I have put together , but for some reason content is just not showing at all , only selected elements!

Please view http://www.jn-design.co.uk/test/flyer.html in Chrome and then IE to view the comparison

It appears to be certain elements within P tags?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try closing your h2 element. It's missing and may be broking the rendering on IE.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="hi_life"><h2>Hi-Life Diners Club </div>
```

You miss the closing h2 tag

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
text-indent: -9999px;
```

and it will show on IE too

Comment: That is not the problem area , if you view in chrome you will see large chunks of paragraphs are not appearing at all...

Comment: That was in the problem area too (you have multiple occurences of text-indent), and doing that on IE with Developer Toolbar resolved the issue. But as answered by other people, the real problem was the not-closed h2 of course :)

Answer (score 0):

inside the class savings_green, try and set the width and the height : width: 540px;
height: 75px;

Comment: I have set the width and height already for that class within the CSS :
 .savings_green{
  font-size: 33px;
  color: #80bd57;
  width:540px;
  height:75px;
  margin-top: 55px;
 }